# 12.04 server, All external services not connecting after reboot

Tags: 12.04, connection

I have just updated my server and rebooted and now my SSH, apache and some other services will not allow connection from external clients. I have disabled UFW and turned off modsecurity but neither of these make any difference. I have tried a tcpdump on port 80 and my custom ssh port and both show that the nic is receiving the packets. My apache logs show no indication that any external requests are hitting apache, but then as I can't connect over SSH I don't think this is an apache issue.

I recently applied security measures as described here : [Securing Ubuntu](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics)

I also performed these measures on 2 other 12.04 servers and they are still responding to external requests. Luckily this is a VM so I can access the terminal via vSphere.

I am relatively new to linux so I have come to the end of my knowledge and do not know what to try next.

Please help :)

Many thanks.

Bev.

Comment: I have just created another ubuntu VM with the same IP and could connect to that via SSH, so I know the routing is fine before the troublesome ubuntu box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this issue in the end by purging UFW from the system and then re-installing it. My rationale was that considering ALL ports and services were affected it had to be a firewall/network layer issue.

Hope this helps someone else.